# Require Credits Footer

Tags: php, javascript, footer

I am wondering if there is a way to require that the credits footer be used (even in child themes). I don't care if they add to it, but I would like to keep credit for the theme creation. I assume I can do this in JS but just wanted to see if anyone else has done it in php or an easier way (WITHOUT A PLUGIN).

EDIT: to be more specific, if they remove my footer provided in the theme, I want the page to not work and give a warning message explaining not to do that and have the page not function until it is resolved.

Comment: why did someone downvote? This is a legitimate question.

Answer (score 1):

I believe (off of top of head) that theme authors cannot 'force' attribution code as part of the theme. The theme must allow for removal of the attributions. (Can't find the doc standards for this at the moment.)

You should be able to edit the theme code that shows the attribution, although that is not recommended. Better to create a child theme, then change that. Otherwise, a theme upgrade may overwrite your changes.

As a theme author, the WP theme requirements do not allow you to 'force' attribution on the user.  IIRC.

Comment: Only if the resulting theme is going to be submitted for review and inclusion I think. I looked all around and that was the only definitive answer I could find.

Answer (score 0):

What you are proposing is in direct violation of the license that your theme's PHP files are governed under which is the GNU Public License v2 or GPLv2. 
The GPLv2 is called a "viral license" meaning that any derivative works will automatically inherit the GPLv2 license as well. Your theme is a derivative of WordPress which is why this license also applies to your theme's PHP files regardless of what license you might otherwise want to use.

One of the requirements of the GPLv2 is that people are free to copy, modify, and distribute the work. So your question is basically asking how to stop people from making a modification that you don't want them to make and enforcing it.

Any CSS, JavaScript, Image files and so forth are not covered by the GPL as they are not necessarily required by WordPress. But your PHP files are covered because they are dependent on WordPress to function.

Answer (score -1):

Any code you provide in the theme can be overridden in a child theme, so there is no way to make sure the footer isn't removed.

The only thing you could do is obscure stuff (like an unreadable, minified js script that breaks the theme if it isn't there), so less skilled programmers won't be able to figure out how you enforce the footer.

Comment: thats kind of what I was thinking just didn't know if there was another way I was missing.  thanks!